# Compiling/Joining CoffeeScript files in correct order

Tags: coffeescript

Correct me if I am wrong, but it appears that CoffeeScript does not compile/join code (each class has its own file) in the correct order.

If I have these classes in the following files:

**Button.coffee**

```
class Button extends UIComponent
```

**UIComponent.coffee**

```
class UIComponpent
```

When I compile these classes (using the --join flag), it outputs the classes in the incorrect order (i.e. putting Button ahead of UIComponent). So when the referenced .js file is used on a web page, it throws the "Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" error

Is this an issue that anyone else experiences? If so, is the standard use of CoffeeScript to not use classes? I'm just confused on why this doesn't appear to be a standard implementation? Perhaps I am using CoffeeScript incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CoffeeScript** isn't responsible for your dependency management.
You could use something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) to define your dependencies, then use **CoffeeScript** to compile your **JavaScript** files separately, and then use the **r.js** optimiser to minify and concatenate your compiled **JS**.

Comment: I started to explore that after I posted the question last night. Thanks for the help!